# PHP POST/GET request to internal link

Tags: php

How can I make a POST/GET request from one of my controllers to another controller? Say the GET request on my resource `/myResource1` wants to make a GET request to `/myResource2` and return the information.

From what I know, `cURL` should not be used for internal use right?

Comment: depending on what you need to do, you can use `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Ever heard of Front Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask can be done with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)":

```
<?php 
   $stringResponse  = file_get_contents('www.unicorns.com/myResource2');

   return $stringResponse;
?>
```

However, it will be much cleaner to move the code from `Resource2`, and just include and call it from both  controllers.